# How to pass an object with an unknown type to a Class with an unknown type

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am currently working on a homework assignment for a Java programming course I am taking.  I am not asking for an exact answer, but for some guidance.

The problem I'm working on is this:

I have a filter class that implements a Filter interface.  This interface has just one method - `matches(T element)`

I have configured my filter method to check an Integer that is being passed in for prime-ness.

There is also a decorator class that decorates a collection class to only display objects that pass the filter.

I'm having problems getting the contains(Object o) method to work correctly.

Basically the `contains(Obj o)` method in the  `FilteredCollection` class should first check to see if the object passes the filter, and then if it does, call the undecorated `contains()` method on that object.

Assuming I want to be able to use this `FilteredCollection` class with many different types of filters, How can I determine what type of object is being passed in, and then be able to pass that object to the current Filter that's being implemented.

Here is my `PrimeNumberFilter` Class:

```
public class PrimeNumberFilter implements Filter<Integer> {

public boolean matches(Integer e) {
    int n = e.intValue();
    if (n != 2 && n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

---

Then here is my shortened `FilteredCollection` Class:

```
class FilteredCollection<T> implements Collection<T> {

Collection<T> fc;
Filter<T> currentFilter;

private FilteredCollection(Collection<T> coll, Filter<T> filter) {

    this.fc = coll;
    this.currentFilter = filter;

}

public static <T> FilteredCollection<T> decorate(Collection<T> coll,
    Filter<T> filter) {

    return new FilteredCollection<T>(coll, filter);
}

public boolean contains(Object o) {

    //What do I do here?
    return fc.contains(o);
}
```

The object being passed in to the contains method has to pass the filter, in this case a `PrimeNumberFilter`.

The error I'm getting is it keeps wanting to cast the object to type T, and I know that this will never work because of erasure.

I've done a ton of research, and I've boiled it down to needing to use reflection.

The only hint my instructor will give me is that object only has a few methods I can use, and I should use one of those.

Thanks for your help!

**EDIT:**  One of the requirements of the project is to NOT cast an object to T in any method.  So while these answers are great, I am not able to use any of them.

Comment: I'm not getting a clear idea of your instructor's restrictions on you.  I'm afraid you won't be able to use an answer I give you.

Comment: change definition to `public boolean contains(T o) {`

Comment: @hoaz that won't compile, at least any way I tried

Comment: wouldnt a check for instanceOf T work inside contains...?

Comment: If your instructor has suggested you use methods on object, check out the last paragraph of the Collection<T> documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html.  It describes what the "contains" method specification in regards to collections.  See also method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains(java.lang.Object).  Edit: Collection is an interface; what is fc's actual type that you are delegating contains to in the above code?

Comment: @flatline FilteredCollection is just a Generic type.  The type is undetermined until runtime.  In this case, the type is Integer, but if I was to implement some sort of String filter, then it would be string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method to use is `Object.equals(Object)`. You can iterate the collection `fc` and check if it contains an element wich `equals(o)`. If so, continue on with said element (which is of type `T`).

```
for(T e : fc) {
    if(o.equals(e)) {
        // carry on with e
    }
}
```

You might also want to cover `o == null`.

Comment: This was exactly the right answer!  I understand how this works, and I thank you!

Comment: This will violate the contract of the collection, you have to include a call to the filter as the

Comment: What do you think the `contains` method does beneath the covers - depending on the implementation it not a million miles from this ( although it's optimised in `HashSet` due to the `Map` used to hold the actual data).  The problem is that unless you include a call to the `Filter` in the contains you could create a `FilteredCollection` using a `Collection` that contains `1` and your `myFilteredCollection.contains(1)` would return `true` but `1` would not be present when you iterate over `myFilteredCollection`, which violate the `Collection` contract.

Comment: @NickHolt What do you think "carry on with e" means? (It means 'do your filtering logic here'.) Btw. I have a very good grasp on how the jdk collection implementations work. I also know what 'unchecked cast' means, but newacct already pointed that out to you.

Comment: I see, it wasn't clear that 'carry on with e' meant apply the filter to e.  But that's the point, I don't see what the loop buys you over simply calling `contains` and you still have to do the cast to invoke the filter or am I missing something?

Comment: @NickHolt The cast can be avoided. Since `o.equals(e)` one can call `currentFilter.matches(e)` instead of `currentFilter.matches(o)`.

Comment: Yes, sorry just occurred to me that's what you intended.  Though there's still a cast happening, admittedly checked at compile time, in the use of generics and the iterable.  I'd potentially still be worried about altering the performance profile of the wrapped collection by iterating over the contents, but that's a whole other discussion.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

The problem is due to the `java.util.Collection.contains(Object o)` interface method not being generically typed. This is outside of your control.

**Option 1: Simple approach**

In your implementation of that method you can cast:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return o != null && currentFilter.matches((T)o) && fc.contains(o);
}
```

**Option 2: Add a getParameterType() method to the Filter interface**

This method would return the generic type of the filter as implemented in the various subclasses.

```
interface Filter<T> {
    boolean matches(T parameter);
    Class<T> getParameterType();
}
```

Then...

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    return o != null && currentFilter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()) && currentFilter.matches((T)o) && fc.contains(o);
}
```

**Option 3: Determine generic type via reflection**

Technically the generic type of your filter will **not actually be erased** at runtime. Type erasure does not apply here because PrimeNumberFilter is an actual class which implements a generically typed interface.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    Class<?> genericTypeOfFilter = getGenericTypeOfFilter(currentFilter);
    return o != null && genericTypeOfFilter.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass()) && currentFilter.matches((T)o) && fc.contains(o);
}

static <T> Class<T> getGenericTypeOfFilter(Filter<T> filter) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "UnnecessaryLocalVariable"})
        Class<T> type = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)filter.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
        return type;
    }
   catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpectedly failed to read generic type of filter: " + filter, e);
    }
}
```

---

If it was my code I'd go with Option 2 in this case, it is more robust than relying on reflection.

Comment: Thank you for the great response, but a requirement I forgot to mention is that a cast from Object to T is not allowed.

Comment: Okay no problem, thanks for the upvote anyway. Be aware that cast to T is the correct and more efficient approach in most cases though.

Comment: @user2145333: and why not?

Answer (score 0):

The type cast to `T` will work, you just need to be careful to catch `ClassCastException`s because you can't check the type prior to the cast due to erasure.

This will leave you with something like:

```
public boolean contains(Object other) 
{
  try
  {   
    return currentFilter.matches((T)other) && fc.contains(other);
  }
  catch (ClassCastException e)
  {
    //Add some logging.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Using exceptions in this way is generally frowned upon, but in this instance, you don't have much choice.

Comment: I don't think catching `ClassCastException` is good enough.  For example, I could write a "Sets of size 3" filter which takes a Set and checks `s.size() == 3`.  The predicate then might accept a `Collection` with size 3 as well because it never actually casts it to a Set, it just uses the `Collection.size` method...  Haven't prototyped it out to prove it, but I'd be a little worried.

Comment: @StevenSchlansker: well, then your predicate just test for collections of size 3. what's the problem?

Comment: "The type cast to T will work" Technically, the cast to `T` does absolutely nothing at runtime. However, once passed to `.matches()`, *that method* may or may not cast it.

Comment: The cast is required in order to compile and catching a `ClassCastException` protects against an error when the invocation of the filter causes the cast to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Since the contains method makes use of .equals, and .equals is qn overridden version of the one in Object, I would think about making a new Collection with the Object parameter type, so for example ArrayList then use it's addAll method to add everything from your T type collection - this will work because all classes inherit from Object. Then when it uses the equals method, it will still be the one from class T (assuming T has overridden it). It's not perhaps the perfect approach, but I think it is simpler and neater than trying to check if the Object can be cast to T.

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {

    Collection<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
    temp.addAll(fc);
    return temp.contains(o);
}
```